# Android app shortcut is not working. Getting error "Failed to read the app data cannot start the app"

Tags: android, shortcut

I have Created an App Shortcut of my app. But when i click on that shortcut it says
"Failed to read the app data cannot start the app"

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

this line in my manifest file and also i have added

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
```

This line in my Main Intent filter:-

Here  is my `shortcuts.xml` file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_trackconsignment"
        android:shortcutId="tracking"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/track"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/track">

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="in.vesolve.deliveryflyking.activities.revamp"
            android:targetClass="in.vesolve.deliveryflyking.activities.revamp.ConsignmentTrackActivity"
            />
    </shortcut>
</shortcut>
```

Output : -
[Shortcut Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmMFT.jpg)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCxs2.jpg)

My device : Relame 7 , Android 10 , Realme UI 1.0

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

In Android manifest file, Add the below code in the launcher activity tag

```
android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *applicationId* in **build.gradle** and *targetPackage* in **xml/shortcuts.xml** should be same.

For example(Assuming as per your code snippet):

```
applicationId "in.vesolve.deliveryflyking" in build.gradle.
```

Then update your target package in shortcuts.xml

```
android:targetPackage="in.vesolve.deliveryflyking"
android:targetClass="in.vesolve.deliveryflyking.activities.revamp.ConsignmentTrackActivity"
```